# OrmliteBaseService --- getHelper()

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm writing an Android SyncAdapter and SyncService and am sub-classes OrmliteBaseService in order to allow the service to use the ORM. On the first attempt the synch works correctly. At some point later Android attempt to stop the sync service and must at some pint call onDestroy. Trouble is when it next comes to sync it appears to call onCreate in the same instance and returns an error when subsequently gettng a db connection. For some reason OrmliteBaseService is designed not to allow onCreate to be run again. Would I be safe altering this behaviour as I can't seem to make the Sync Manager create a new instance every time. Anyone come across this?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you will get better/more answers if you put some sample code for people to look at.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the sample programs.  I believe you need to release the helper in the `onDestroy(...)` method.  Can you show us your code like @Corley mentioned?